# How to select max date and min date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Have table like :

```
 user_id              Date                Status
    1000        2013-04-02 11:46:10.000       IN
    1001        2013-04-02 11:50:08.000       OUT
    1005        2013-04-02 11:46:24.000       IN
    1005        2013-04-02 12:50:04.000       OUT
    1005        2013-04-02 12:50:10.000       OUT
    1045        2013-04-02 14:46:05.000       IN
```

I want select min date of **IN** and max date of **OUT**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select user_id, min(case when status = 'IN' then Date end) as mindate, 
max(case when status = 'OUT' then Date end) as maxdate, status
from tbl
group by user_id, Status
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9430e/6

Another way to do it:

```
select a.user_id, mindate, maxdate
from 
(
    select user_id, min(date) as mindate, Status
    from tbl
    where Status = 'IN'
    group by user_id, Status) a
left join 
(
   select user_id, max(date) as maxdate, Status
   from tbl
   where Status = 'OUT'
   group by user_id, Status) b 
on a.user_id = b.user_id
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9430e/14

Edit:
To check if the min and max date are within date range of your choosing, using the second example add where condition at the end: (if I understood correctly)

```
select a.user_id, mindate, maxdate
from 
(
select user_id, min(date) as mindate, Status
from tbl
where Status = 'IN'
group by user_id, Status) 
a
left join (
select user_id, max(date) as maxdate, Status
from tbl
where Status = 'OUT'
group by user_id, Status) b on a.user_id = b.user_id
where @yourstart date <= maxdate and @yourenddate >= mindate
```

this checks if two dates overlap...

Comment: can you help me i want select this min date and max date where date between getdate() . only one day min and max date

Answer (score 0):

Super simple

```
SELECT Max(Date) FROM MyTable WHERE Status = 'OUT'
SELECT Min(Date) FROM MyTable WHERE Status = 'IN'
```

With on select

```
SELECT (SELECT Max(Date) FROM MyTable WHERE Status = 'OUT') AS MaxOut,
       (SELECT Min(Date) FROM MyTable WHERE Status = 'IN') AS MinIn
```

Comment: I want all data in one select not in two selects